# What is the correct format for dest_addr using XBee Python library?

Tags: python, pyserial, xbee

I am using [python-xbee](https://python-xbee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and Python 3.7 to send API commands from an XBee connected to UART1 on a Beaglebone Black to a remote XBee. Both are Version 1 Pro models.

My remote XBee (the one I am sending commands to) has the following address:

```
SH=0013A200
SL=40DD7DCD
```

When I submit a command using the low portion of the 64-bit address

`xbee.remote_at(dest_addr='\x40\xDD\x7D\xCD', command='0x17', parameter=D0_LOW, frame_id='A')`

I receive the error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xdd' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`

My code is as follows:

```
from xbee import XBee from serial import Serial

PORT = '/dev/ttyO1' 
BAUD = 9600

# Send 0x17 AT command with parameter 04 for low (off), 05 for high (on)
# D0=4 Low
# D0=5 High

D0_LOW = 4 
D0_HIGH = 5

ser = Serial(PORT, BAUD)

xbee = XBee(ser)

xbee.remote_at(dest_addr='\x40\xDD\x7D\xCD', command='0x17', parameter=D0_LOW, frame_id='A')
# Wait for and get the response

print(xbee.wait_read_frame())

ser.close()
```

My question is this - what is the correct format for the dest_addr when the upper and lower bytes are known and no controller is being used (point-to-point only)?

If I change the address to use hex (e.g. \0x40\0xDD\0x7D\0xCD) then the error message is

`The data provided for 'dest_addr' was not 2 bytes long`

Do I need to format the address to ASCII 2 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be running into issues because your `dest_addr` is a regular python string as opposed to a byte string.  You should try the following.

```
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr=b'\x40\xDD\x7D\xCD', command='0x17', parameter=b'\x04', frame_id='A')
```

Comment: Thanks Max. I tried that and I receive the same error - The data provided for 'dest_addr' was not 2 bytes long.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, the address should indeed only be 2 bytes while it's currently specified as 4 bytes.  Can you try running `xbee.send("at", frame='A', command='MY')` and see what it returns?

Comment: The documentation is horrid!  It doesn't explain how to derive a 2 byte address from a 64-bit address.   Running that command waits indefinitely.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the digi-xbee library?

Comment: I would love to but the documentation isn't any better.  I'll have a go at it tomorrow and see if it makes more sense. Long week!

Comment: @Notamachine I actually think that the digi-xbee library is quite well documented: https://xbplib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_doc/configuring_the_xbee_device.html

Comment: Let me re-phrase.  There is a massive amount of documentation available.  The flow is not intuitive to me.  I prefer overview plus examples which are more than 3 lines.  It doesn't mean the documentation it bad.  It just isn't a good fit for the way I learn.  As a researcher, I am used to ingesting very large quantities of information in a short period of time - but each person is different.

Comment: @"Max Feinberg" if you know where in the digi-xbee library docs it describes how to load the module containing IOLine I would be obliged.  I have been going in circles trying to find it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://python-xbee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

> A listing of all supported data frames and their respective fields may be found in xbee.ieee.XBee (or xbee.zigbee.ZigBee for XBee ZB devices) defined as api_responses.

Perhaps you can use `help(xbee.ieee.XBee)` or `help(xbee.zigbee.ZigBee)` (or even `help(xbee.remote_at)`) for a list of the methods and their parameters.

I also saw a `source_addr_long` on that page, so perhaps you can specify a `dest_addr_long` for your `remote_at()` call.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows:

```
remote_xbee='40DD7DCD'
frame_id = b'\x01'

#For D0 Off
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long=remote_xbee,command='D0',parameter='\x04', frame_id=frame_id)
```